# Adding a Wine (.exe) file to open/play files in Thunar's 'Custom Actions'

Tags: command-line, wine, customization, thunar

What is the line parameter in Thunar's "custom actions" that would play a music directory in a Wine (.exe) program?

I want to put Foobar2000 (and possibly other such applications) in [Thunar's Custom Actions](http://thunar.xfce.org/pwiki/documentation/custom_actions) (actions that can be added/edited to be used in the context menu to play music folder's content).

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I put no command parameter at the end of path, the player opens but there is no play and no files in the play list.

If I add any of the listed parameters I get the error

> unknown commandline parameter: /path.to.file

(Giving an answer to this question depends on knowing the CLI command that would have to be added into Thunar - so please look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/218997/47206) too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the `Thunar` command `%F` is probably not going to work when applied to a `Wine` program. Often the best way with `Thunar` custom actions is to use a script and apply the correct parameter to that: i.e.

```
/home/mike/foo_script %F
```

then the parameter can apply to the script.

The script I have experimented with is [at the hydrogenaudio forums](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=54933), and I have modified it slightly, but credit to that forum. There is a lot of useful information on that forum about foobar.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/.wine/drive_c/"Program Files"/foobar2000/
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
filename=`echo z:$1 | sed 's/\\//\\\\/g'`
wine foobar2000.exe "$filename" &
else
wine foobar2000.exe &
fi
```

Copy the script into a text editor, but make sure you place the correct location of your foobar directory in the script, make it executable and enter its location in the `Thunar` custom actions dialogue (as in the screenshot below). As you know, select audio files and folders in the other 'appearance conditions' tab.

[image]

Once it has been added as a `Thunar` custom action with the correct parameters, the script further above allows you to add and then play your music in `Foobar` just by right clicking on a single track or a folder and selecting your custom menu item.

Here is `Foobar` launched with the custom action and playing a folder of Duke Ellington:

[image]

In addition, you could probably modify the script and also use it for other wine applications just by changing the name (foobar2000) of the application and the application folder. Then you could create a new script and another different custom action.

Comment: works for 7zip too