# Add Searchmonkey to Thunar custom actions

Tags: search, command-line, thunar, thunar-custom-actions, searchmonkey

I see [here](http://thunar.xfce.org/pwiki/documentation/custom_actions) that, in order to add as custom action in **Thunar** the search with **gnome-search-tool**, the command is:

> gnome-search-tool –path=%f

and with **catfish** it is different:

> catfish --fileman=thunar --path=%f

(Why the difference, by the way?)

What's the one for **Searchmonkey**?

(The above do not seem to work for it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gnome-search-tool` and `catfish`, command-line options are available and so the programs can integrate into Thunar quite nicely; the `--path=%f` option is important as that means the location of the selected folder (with its files) can be passed on to these search tools so they open at the right folder.

If you enter the name of the program and then add`--help`, you will see all the command-line options for these two search tools: for `gnome-search-tool --help` we have many options such as:

```
 --named=STRING                  Set the text of "Name contains" search option
 --path=PATH                     Set the text of "Look in folder" search option
```

With `catfish` there are similar options, but it used to be essential to specify `--fileman=thunar` in addition to `--path=%f`. This was found to be [necessary](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maryan-linux/+bug/212769) as catfish used to only open the home folder, not the one selected if the fileman workaround was not used. However, it works now with just `--path=%f` with Catfish 0.3.2 and Thunar 1.2.3 on Xubuntu 12.04.

It doesn't seem to be possible to pass any command-line options to `searchmonkey`, and there doesn't seem to be any information available: the mailing-lists and forums seem [pretty empty](http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=175143). Even if you set the filemanager and options in searchmonkey > settings > preferences > systemcalls, and then specify options in the custom action, it doesn't seem to integrate into `Thunar` successfully.

`Searchmonkey` doesn't seem to integrate with other filemanagers either after testing, so it must be because it does not accept any suitable command-line options. The only way to make it integrate would be to create a patch for it and recompile it, which is probably not really worthwhile considering how useful `catfish` is.

Comment: does that mean that a script like in your answer for wine programs (http://askubuntu.com/a/219370/47206) is also out of discussion here?

Comment: @cipricus I tried using a script to see if that would act as a workaround, but `searchmonkey` still didn't open at the selected folder, but only at `/home/mike`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is almost 6 years later yet this workaround is quite nice. In Configure custom actions edit the catfish command from:

```
    catfish --path=%f
```

to

```
    searchmonkey --directory=/
```

or

```
    searchmonkey --directory=/home
```

or any path you like and it will start up ready to search what ever path you insert of course. The first command with the search starting at root (=/) will scan every hard drive you have. So far no command options found to search the folder you would right click upon. Possible to make two context menu entries and have one named root and the other named home or whatever path you like. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, as of Searchmonkey v0.8.3 we now accept the command-line args, like this:

```
$ searchmonkey -d {directory} -f {filename} -t {containing text}
```

For example:

```
$ searchmonkey -d /home/tux -f txt -t linux
```

will open searchmonkey configured to scan directory `/home/tux` to search files containing `txt` in their names and search inside the files for the string `linux`.

ONE to THREE parameters (`-d` and/or `-t` and/or `-f`) are also allowed, and of course `-?` will display help!

Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

Very nice. Here is how I use searchmonkey 0.8.3 in nemo, as a 'search here' script. (placed in `/home/$USER/.local/share/nemo/scripts/`)

```
#!/bin/sh

# This only works with searchmonkey 0.8.3+
#passes nemo directory string to 'obj' string

obj="$NEMO_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"

#This cuts off the first 7 characters from the string.
#Nemo adds 'file://' to the beginning of the directory string.
#It confuses searchmonkey, and must be clipped off.

CURDIR=`echo $obj | cut -c 8-`

#Add this if you want to see the formatted string, before searchmonkey executes.
#(For testing purposes only. not needed)

zenity --info --text=$CURDIR --no-wrap

#executes searchmonkey, and passes formatted directory string to it.

searchmonkey -d $CURDIR
```

Hope this helps anyone using nemo file manager (works in peppermint 10)