# Wine 1.5 %ProgramFiles% error

Tags: 12.10, wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install d3dx9 with winetricks on wine 1.5 from ppa and I keep getting an error. I tried:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.win32 winecfg 
sudo WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.win32 winetricks
```

And still get this error:

```
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
```

If I type `wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%'` into the terminal I get `C:\Program Files` so the path seems correct but not when I run winetricks.

I also tried this [regedit fix](http://code.google.com/p/winetricks/issues/detail?id=90) with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you use sudo in one of your `winetricks` commands: that could be the main problem, as sudo shouldn't be used with `wine` or `winetricks` (only when running `sudo apt-get install wine`); see my comment at the end of my post.*

When I successfully installed d3dx9 to a separate wine prefix, which I see you are also using, I used the below command in the terminal.

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.myprefixname winetricks d3dx9
```

This is part of the voluminous output I got from the command using the `WINEPREFIX`:

```
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/mike/.myprefixname/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32 -L -F d3dx9*.dll /home/mike/.myprefixname/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_d3dx9/apr2006_d3dx9_30_x86.cab
```

You must change `.myprefixname` to the name of your own prefix; for more explanation of wine prefixes and their use, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218049/how-to-reset-setting-of-wine-avoiding-uninstalling-all-applications-in-it).

You only need to specify `WINEARCH=win32` or the 64bit equivalent when you create the prefix, as it can't be altered afterwards, as noted [at WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/x544). `Wine` will also refuse to load if you specify a different `WINEARCH` to the one you created it with.

Just entering in terminal `winetricks d3dx9` would instead install directX to your default `~/.wine` folder.

*It is most **important** to note that when installing things with `winetricks` or using `wine`, you don't need to use sudo, as you are not installing the files to the system, but to your Wine folder or separate wine prefix in your home folder. Using sudo might cause the problem you are experiencing with paths, as is noted on the  [actual link](http://code.google.com/p/winetricks/issues/detail?id=90) given. In the [WineFAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#run_as_root) it notes that

> Running with sudo...has the added bonus of breaking the permissions on your ~/.wine folder in the process. If you have run Wine with sudo you need to fix the permission errors... and then run winecfg to set Wine up again.

So, I should also check your permissions and refer to the [WineFAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8b89c928ce782c014b8b312469223296093e1484) article, as you will need to reset your permissions even if you reinstall `wine`. If you have used sudo with `wine` and now root owns some of the files, you will need to change the permissions by running the following commands from the [WineFAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8b89c928ce782c014b8b312469223296093e1484):

```
cd $HOME  
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .wine
```

Replace `.wine` with your prefix if you use a `WINEPREFIX` or use the command for both your `.wine` folder and your prefix if you have both.

Comment: Thank you, the `sudo` was the problem. I purged and re-installed Wine, then set permissions accordingly and `winetricks` works now fine without `sudo` and without errors.

Comment: The problem is sudo, try: sudo su and wine command as root.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem giving my user privilegies:

```
YOURUSERNAME@nt401: ~ $ sudo chgrp -R YOURUSERNAME ~/.cache/winetricks/
YOURUSERNAME@nt401: ~ $ sudo chown -R YOURUSERNAME ~/.cache/winetricks/
```

hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by using export `WINEARCH=win64` instead of `export WINEARCH=win32`

This is because the .wine directory present in your home directory is 64 bit and not 32.
Thats why after `echo %ProgramFiles%` returns as it cannot find a .wine directory for 32 bit arch.