# Installing Wine On a different USB device to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, wine

Can someone please tell me how to use Ubuntu 12.10 to install Wine onto a separate USB memory stick? I've looked for hours on the Internet with no luck so far, so help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootable USB with [persistence mode](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/persistence) (same kind of settings in other usb creator is also available).

Boot using it, install wine and other applications.

Comment: Web-E, i need Wine to be on a separate memory stick to the operating system, not the same one.

Comment: but wine isn't portable :) ..You need some OS where you will install wine. pretty interesting info [here](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=67081)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that might be useful for your purposes, although because of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout), we don't usually run 'portable' programs from flash drives, as one often does on Windows.

(Firstly, you should format your drive with a filesystem that fully supports permissions like ext4)

1) The first involves compiling wine, as you won't be able to install a deb to a non-standard location using the normal package manager.

As the [wineFAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-0c8aaba3983aaf8fb9e0ae1a52f7d7e65fea9126) mentions, you could compile wine yourself with a suitable prefix so that it is installed in a non-standard location. However, you would then have to make sure that all the right libraries, etc were linked and could be found by the program. You would have to run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for various libraries, etc as the FAQ explains, so that your compiled `wine` looked for the libraries in your custom directory. You could definitely run your compiled `wine` from that drive once it was compiled and all the linking set up, but it might be tricky to set up the linking successfully.

2) The second involves installing `wine` first.

However, there is then a way you could get close to what you want and have an independent wine folder from your system default `~/.wine`, and this could be done by creating a `wineprefix` in your flash drive.

You could format your flash drive with a filesystem that fully supports permissions like ext4, and then you can create a `wineprefix` on your flash drive with

```
WINEPREFIX=/media/UnixFlash/wine winecfg
```

This would be a way of running programs from the suitably formatted flash drive, and using a `wineprefix` would keep the applications and settings apart from the main `~/.wine` folder which could be set up differently. I discuss more about wineprefixes in this answer:

- [How to reset setting of Wine, avoiding uninstalling all applications in it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218049/how-to-reset-setting-of-wine-avoiding-uninstalling-all-applications-in-it)