# Is Grasshopper for Rhino also running in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, wine, plugins

Does anybody got to run *[Grasshopper for Rhino 5](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/)* <sup>1</sup>? Could you please share some info about how to install it?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Grasshopper – algorithmic modeling for Rhino</sub>

Comment: Close Voters, why is this question unclear?

Comment: Have you installed Rhino via wine?

Answer (score 0):

Rhino has no Linux version. Use Blender instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Despite the fact that officially there is not a Rhino version for Ubuntu, some guys got it to work.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/271375/rhino-3d-5-0-64bit

Comment: The only way to find out if something works under wine is to test it, and if something works for me it would not mean it will work the same for you.