# Pro Evolution Soccer 2013 via Wine on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wine

I've tried installing PES 2013 via wine. It worked, the installation process is finished.

The game doesn't run correctly.

The game reads my VRAM as 128 MB, mine is 512 MB. I think I must install the drivers or something so it reads it correctly?

When I run the game it crashes with a weird error.

EDIT: After installing wine 1.5.27 the game doesn't crash, instead it keeps loading, but nothing happens.

I think the whole problem is with my graphics card, it's read as 128 MB instead of 512 MB.
How to install the proper graphics drivers?

Comment: `When I run the game it crashes with a weird error.` No-one on askubuntu owns a crystal ball so ...

Comment: Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x0000000c in 32-bit code (0x01210690).

That's the first line.

Didn't think anyone would know what to do with such an error log.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Close voters: There is no need to close it. It should not be closed as 'off topic' unless `wine` is now off topic! This question has been answered and the OP has confirmed the solution; it was to do with a setting in `wine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of letting `wine` detect the amount of video card memory available, you can explicitly set it with `winetricks`. This can sometimes work, and is a possibility, as is investigating the other graphical tweaks available with `winetricks`.

You can run the following, for example, to set the videomemory to 512, rather than let `wine` try to detect the video memory available:

```
winetricks videomemorysize=512
```

It is important to note that this will affect the **default** WINEPREFIX (`$HOME/.wine`) only. **If** you have other wineprefixes, you will have to specify your particular WINEPREFIX; for example:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.otherprefix winetricks videomemorysize=512
```

You can also use the gui version of `winetricks` from the applications menu and select the wineprefix and then select change settings. Other options available for setting video memory are:

[image]

There is no way to tell whether these settings will work with your system, and you may have to tweak other settings such as shaders, etc. I should refer to [the wine appdb page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14377) and the [winetricks wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) and [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ). You may have to investigate how `wine` and `wined3d` is detecting your video card and its capabilities.

It also might be worth reinstalling and using a fresh WINEPREFIX, as that can sometimes solve problems (see my answer [here for how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218049/how-to-reset-setting-of-wine-avoiding-uninstalling-all-applications-in-it/220758#220758)), as well as using the current development version of `wine` from the official [Ubuntu wine team ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa).

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Now the game runs normally. One thing so, it's kinda slower on Ubuntu than on Windows on the same PC. Anything to speed it up a bit?

Comment: @user147037 Good! I should accept the answer by clicking the tick near the answer. As to why it should run slower under `wine`, that is difficult to say, but you could probably alter some in game quality settings or the resolution.